# Apache Superset Error: An unexpected occurred while executing the report: list index out of range

Tags: python, docker-compose, apache-superset

I was able to successfully setup superset in Compute Engine, i have the Dockerfile, docker-compose.ym and superset_config.py

Everything looks good especially the async queries, but when generating Alerts and Reports every minute the error occured.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7.4-slim-buster

LABEL maintainer="reymart.betana@gmail.com"

ENV FLASK_APP="superset"

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y unzip wget build-essential python-psycopg2 libpq-dev postgresql libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev git \
  && apt-get clean

RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    apt install -y --no-install-recommends ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/90.0.4430.24/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    chmod +x chromedriver && \
    mv chromedriver /usr/bin && \
    apt autoremove -yqq --purge && \
    apt clean && \
    rm -f google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb chromedriver_linux64.zip

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install apache-superset

RUN superset db upgrade

RUN export FLASK_APP=superset

RUN superset fab create-admin --username=admin --firstname=admin --lastname=admin --email=test@gmail.com --password=admin

RUN superset load_examples

RUN superset init 

RUN pip install gevent -U

RUN pip install flower

RUN pip install psycopg2

RUN pip install pybigquery

RUN pip install authlib

RUN pip install Pillow

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY superset_config.py superset_config.py

RUN export PYTHONPATH=/usr/src/app/superset_config.py
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.8"

services:
 
 worker:
  image: superset
  restart: always
  depends_on:
    - superset
  command: celery worker --app=superset.tasks.celery_app:app --pool=gevent --concurrency=500

 flower:
  image: superset
  restart: always
  ports:
   - "5555:5555"
  depends_on:
    - superset
    - worker
    - beat
  command: celery flower --address=0.0.0.0 --app=superset.tasks.celery_app:app

 beat:
  image: superset
  restart: always
  depends_on:
    - superset
  command: celery beat --app=superset.tasks.celery_app:app --pidfile /tmp/celerybeat.pid --schedule /tmp/celerybeat-schedule

 superset:
  image: superset
  restart: always
  ports:
   - "8080:8080"
  command: gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8080 -w 10 -k gevent --timeout 120 --limit-request-line 0 --limit-request-field_size 0 "superset.app:create_app()"
```

**Logs**

```
worker_1    | Taking a PNG screenshot or url http://superset.com/superset/dashboard/8/
worker_1    | [2021-05-20 07:15:07,236: INFO/MainProcess] Taking a PNG screenshot or url http://superset.com/superse
t/dashboard/8/
worker_1    | Caching thumbnail: 97160ab7ea43b549ea4ec3827375ca49
worker_1    | [2021-05-20 07:15:07,652: INFO/MainProcess] Caching thumbnail: 97160ab7ea43b549ea4ec3827375ca49
worker_1    | Done caching thumbnail
worker_1    | [2021-05-20 07:15:07,656: INFO/MainProcess] Done caching thumbnail
worker_1    | An unexpected occurred while executing the report: list index out of range
worker_1    | [2021-05-20 07:15:07,665: ERROR/MainProcess] An unexpected occurred while executing the report: list index out of range
```

Thumbnail cache works fine but when submitting the reports through email "list index out of range" happened.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Migrating OP's solution from a comment to an answer</sub>

> The problem was the SMTP config from `superset_config.py` was empty had put some values on it.